# Ca't find JEE source in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I am using JEE 7 through JBoss Wildfly 10, as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
    <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am using Java 8. One thing is particularly annoying and that's in Eclipse I can't find the source doc for most classes under Javax... library, but not all. For instance, for these import declaration:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
```

When my mouse pointer moves to those import declarations, only `EntityManager` can show its documentation as a tool tip, and all others only shows:

```
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.
```

Another example:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
```

Only `NotNull` and `Size` can't display their source documentation, while all others can. All classes under the package "Java" don't have this problem.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Right-click on the project > Maven > Download Sources. It should make m2e resolve all sources for your project, si you'll get hover and good completion for most types.

You can also set this Download Sources to be the default behavior via the Preferences.

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=500552 on this topic.